# How to iterate through data frame on R and remove certain vaules

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate through a data frame on R and remove all values below a certain threshold (.2). Filter doesn't work as it removes the entire rows that contain such values, but I only want to remove the individual data points.

I receive this error message for the if statement and have no idea why:

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

My code so far:

```
    bigpeak<- function(x){
      for(i in nrow(x)){
        for(j in ncol(x)){
          if (x[i, j] < .2){
            (x[i, j] == NA)
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: `is.na(x) <- x < .2`, usually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sapply(data,function(j) ifelse(j<.2,NA,j))
```